# What is the difference between CGPath and UIBezierPath()?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cgpath

At the moment, I'm trying to work out how to animate a custom button which I have an image of and have the coordinates of but I've found that you can create a button/object both by using the CGPath class or the UIBezierPath class. Can somebody please tell me what the difference between the two are?

Answer (score 26):

[CGPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/) is an opaque type from the CoreGraphics library, while [UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html) is an Obj-C class in UIKit. UIBezierPath is a wrapper around CGPath (you can convert between them easily), with a more object-oriented interface and a few convenience methods. Using CGPath may be marginally faster as it doesn't have to go through Obj-C (although who knows how it works with Swift) and it has more advanced functions like [CGPathApply](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathApply). Importantly, UIBezierPath conforms to NSCoding, meaning you get serialization/deserialization for free.

tl;dr: use UIBezierPath unless you have some reason not to.

Comment: thanks for the information it was actually very helpful! As you can probably see, I'm basically an absolute beginner. However, what I was trying to get at is that I was trying to create a path for a button, which I have but only in pictures. It simply consists of a green circular progress bar which I believe is called a transition from one state to another like in the website below. The original website I have been looking for guidance is the following: http://robb.is/working-on/a-hamburger-button-transition/     but I need help as to how to fully implement this into my project with my button.

Comment: This post here gives a nice explanation why this answer is incorrect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327817/why-is-uibezierpath-faster-than-core-graphics-path

Comment: `UIBezierPath` has a coordinate system different from `CGPath`: in `CGPath` (Quartz 2D) [the origin is at the bottom-left](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-CJBBAEEC) while in `UIBezierPath` (UIKit) [the origin is at the top-left](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH11-SW5). This bit me once.

Comment: tl;dr goes on top ;)

Answer (score 11):

To expand a bit on what jtbandes wrote, there's another distinction: `CGPath` is just a mathematical description of a shape. It has no drawing-specific properties or capabilities.  Instead, drawing properties are part of the `CGContext` as is the actual drawing operation. You set things like color, line width, etc. on the context before the drawing operation, but those are not part of the path itself.

By contrast, `UIBezierPath` has drawing properties and drawing operations.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. CGPaths are drawn with [CGContextStrokePath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextStrokePath) and other such functions.

Comment: That's a function on a `CGContext`. My main point, because it has confused people in the past, is that a `CGPath` doesn't have, for example, a line thickness or a line dash pattern.